# Evesham (possibly Mitac) Laptop 8889 Drivers

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, drivers

I'm trying to install drivers for Windows XP for my Evesham/Mitac 8889 laptop.

AMD Sempron mobile 3000+
512mb RAM (64mb Shared GFX)
80GB HDD

The OEM is no longer trading (and has not been for a number of years) and a search for the drivers has resulted in lot of people searching but no actual drivers.

Is there a way I can get these drivers?

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer to something?

Comment: Ok, but where is the link?

Comment: See below now, sorry took a while to upload them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I have 'nuked and paved' a couple of these laptops. I came across the original Drivers CD, as the OEM is no longer trading here in the UK (and has not been for a number of years) a number of people are searching online for drivers without much success.

I am providing these drivers for download here without any other support or warranties.

Disclaimer: Download these at your own risk, I will not be held legally responsible for any outcome from using these files. You only have my word that they come from an original CD and that the only modification I have undertaken is zipping to assist in providing them.

- [Readme.txt](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/README.TXT) - Info regarding installing drivers.
- [User Guides](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/Guide.zip) - User guides for DU, EN, FR, GR, IT & SP (.PDF Format).
- [Audio Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/Audio.zip) - Realtek AC'97
- [Cardbus Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/CardBus.zip) - ENE CB1410
- [Chipset Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/Chipset.zip) - VIA
- [CPU Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/CPU.zip) - AMD Sempron
- [LAN Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/Lan.zip) - VIA Rhine II
- [Modem Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/Modem.zip) - Agere Systems AC'97
- [RT2560 Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/RT2560.zip) - IEEE 802.11g MiniPCI  Wireless Adaptor
- [Touchpad Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/Touchpad.zip)  - Synaptics Touchpad v7.11.9
- [VGA Drivers](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66653574/8889/Vga.zip) - VIA/S3G UniChrome Pro IGP

Comment: Note: I couldn't get the Wireless driver to install, but installing automagically from Windows Update fixed the issue.